# Reading data from excel in selenium C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, automation

I'm trying to read username and password from excel sheet while using Selenium in C# .NET. Below is the code:

```
using excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

public void TestMethod1()
{
       excel.Application xlApp = new excel.Application();
       excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"D:\Test\TestData.xlsx");
       excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = **xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];**
       excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;
 }
```

I'm getting the following error at the text that is marked in bold in above code:

> Error CS0656  Missing compiler required member
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.Convert'   Read Data From
>   Excel_Office  c:\users\tabish.khan\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\Read Data From Excel_Office\Read Data From
>   Excel_Office\OfficeReadExcel.cs   18  Active

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you google the error message? What did you find? What did you try to fix it?

Comment: @Mark, yes I tried googling the error. None of the solutions worked. One of the solutions asked me to add the Microsoft.CSharp.dll file. This too didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error with my C# Class Library project. I'm using .NET Framework 4.6 and I used NuGet to install the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel assembly:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

Here is a simplified version of the code which causes this error:

```
using MSExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace ProjectReader
{
    public class ExcelExport
    {

        public ExcelExport()
        {
            xlApp = new MSExcel.Application();
            xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        }

        public void CreateFile()
        {
            object missingValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            foreach (MSExcel.Worksheet sht in xlWorkBook.Sheets)
            {
                if (xlWorkBook.Worksheets.Count > 1)
                {
                    sht.Delete();
                }
            }

            **xlWorkSheet = (MSExcel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets[1];**
        }

        private MSExcel.Application xlApp;
        private MSExcel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        private MSExcel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    }
}
```

Interestingly, I have no issues referencing the worksheets in the foreach loop just above the offending line.

Answer (score -1):

**Use the following steps:-**

1. Go to your project and right click.
2. Click on Add then click on Reference..
3. Select `Microsoft.CSharp` and click on OK button then clean and
   rebuild your project.