# Missing compiler required member Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder.Convert

Tags: c#, excel

I`m using Excel with c# and get an error in this line (using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;)

```
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
```

> "Missing compiler required member 'microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.binder.convert'"

I tried to add reference for **Microsoft.CSharp dll**. but couldn`t find it in the list. In **csproj** file it looks like i already have it.

> Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"

Target Framework - **.Net Framework 4.6.1**

Can somebody, please, help to understand what is wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing compiler required member 'microsoft.csharp.runtimebinder.binder.convert'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637389/missing-compiler-required-member-microsoft-csharp-runtimebinder-binder-convert)

Comment: Duplicate of [Reading data from excel in selenium C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901883/reading-data-from-excel-in-selenium-c-sharp)